# Running spark with mesos and spark package on hdfs

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hdfs, mesos, mesosphere

I tried to run pyspark with mesos, and my spark package is uploaded to local accessable hdfs.

However, whenever I tried to launch the shell, always got following error

```
16/04/18 22:21:33 INFO CoarseMesosSchedulerBackend: Blacklisting Mesos slave a8509a2e-fad8-485d-850e-8243fd2ee449-S0 due to too many failures; is Spark installed on it?
```

I have added the following to spark-env.sh

```
export MESOS_NATIVE_JAVA_LIBRAR=/usr/local/lib/libmesos.so
export SPARK_EXECUTOR_URI=hdfs://ipaddress:9000/spark/spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.6
```

But seems slave still cannot find spark package to execute. How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Does your mesos-slave have HADOOP_HOME configured? And you should have **tar.gz** file like spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.6.tar.gz in hdfs.